# How to make a function that identifies every list item as a string, float, or integer then prints a list like [str, int....]

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a hard time trying to get it to identify every individual list item. I keep trying to use [i] but it is not working...

```py
def identify(list_obj):
    stats = {}
    for i in items:
        if type(list_obj) == int:
            print("int")
        if type(list_obj) == str:
            print("str")
        if type(list_obj) == float:
            print("float")
        else:
            print("null")
    return list_obj

print(identify(list5))
```

Comment: You loop over items, but items is nowhere defined. You need to loop over list_obj and the if statements must contain the i, so for i in list_obj: ... if type(i) == int: etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, but needed some improvements:
 - list5 must be a proper list
 - you need to loop over list_obj
 - you need to change if to elif and test on i

see below

```
def identify(list_obj):

    stats = []

    for i in list_obj:
        if type(i) == int:
            stats.append((i, 'int'))
            print("int")

        elif type(i) == str:
            stats.append((i, 'str'))
            print("str")

        elif type(i) == float:
            stats.append((i, 'float'))
            print("float")

        else:
            stats.append((i, 'null'))
            print("null")

    return stats

list5 = [3, 'a snake', 10, None]  # list5 must be a proper list
print(identify(list5))
```

result:

```
int
str
int
null
[(3, 'int'), ('a snake', 'str'), (10, 'int'), (None, 'null')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You loop over `items` but you didn't declare `items` in your code.

So you should loop over `list_object` to specify the type of each `item`

```py
def identify(list_objects):
    """
    It takes a list of objects and specifies the type of each object in the list.
    """
    handler_dict = {
        int: 'int',
        str: 'str',
        float: 'float',
        list: 'list',
        dict: 'dict'
    }

    return [handler_dict.get(type(obj), 'unknown') for obj in list_objects]
```

**Test**

```
>>> list_objects = [1, 'a', [1, 2], {'a': 1}, 1.0]
>>> print(identify(list_objects))
out: ['int', 'str', 'list', 'dict', 'float']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that *will* work, provided you use the correct variable names:

```
def identify(items):
    types = []
    for item in items:
        if   type(item) == int  : types.append("int")
        elif type(item) == str  : types.append("str")
        elif type(item) == float: types.append("float")
        elif type(item) == list : types.append("list")
        else:                     types.append("unknown")
    return types

list5 = [3, 'a snake', 10.2, [1, 2]]
print(identify(list5))
```

The output of that is:

```
['int', 'str', 'float', 'list']
```

---

You could also use the Pythonic:

```
def identify(items):
    return [str(type(item)).split("'")[1] for item in items]
```

which constructs a list of the textual representation of each type (like `"<type 'int'>"`) and massages it so you get only the `int` bit).